# Reshape a data frame into a wide shape

Tags: r

The data contains two variables: id and grade. Each id can have multiple records 
for each grade.

```
dat <- data.frame(id = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,4,5,5,5),
                  grade = c("a", "b", "c", "a", "a", "b", "b", "d", "f", "c", "a", "e", "f"))
```

I want to reshape the data into a wide shape such that each id has only one record
and each unique grade becomes a single column. The value of each column is either 0 or 1, 
depending on the grades for each id.

The final data set looks like:

```
id  a   b   c   d   e   f
1   1   1   1   0   0   0
2   1   1   0   0   0   0
3   0   0   0   1   0   1
4   0   0   1   0   0   0
5   1   0   0   0   1   1
```

I tried this, but no luck.

```
  n.dat <- reshape(dat, timevar = "grade",idvar = c("id"),direction = "wide")
```

Comment: Maybe `+(table(dat) > 0)`?

Comment: Thanks, @DavidArenburg.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could simply `table` the values, then convert to logical based on `> 0` condition and then convert back to numeric using the `+` unary operator (or if you want less golfed, by simply `+ 0`)

```
+(table(dat) > 0)
#     grade
# id  a b c d e f
#   1 1 1 1 0 0 0
#   2 1 1 0 0 0 0
#   3 0 0 0 1 0 1
#   4 0 0 1 0 0 0
#   5 1 0 0 0 1 1
```